# Compare column A and Column C and then if match found then update Column D with Column B

Tags: excel-2010

Please can anyone help out me doing this ?

1. I have four column. Column A, B, C, D, E and F
2. Need to compare Column A with Column C (not in sequence/ order)
3. If match found, first compare Column B with Column D - Then Match or Not match in Column E
4. If it is Not match, update the value from Column B to column F

.

```
Id(1)  Status   Id      Status   Match/ Not match   Updated status
29583  Closed   26298   Closed    ?                 (from column B)
29926  Closed   30417   New
29912  Closed   30419   Closed
29837  Closed   29011   Closed
30293  New      29575   New
29581  New      29353   New
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `Match/Not Match column` can contain something like this:

`=IF(A1=C1, IF(B1=D1, "Match", "Not Match"), "Not Match")`

In column F you can put something like this:

`=IF(E1="Not Match", B1, "")`

You can then just copy this formula to the rest of the column.